# Listing files in directory created today

Tags: r, list, date, filter, zip

In R, I'm trying to list the files in a directory that have been created today. What works now is the code below, but the directory is a growing one and has many files. This causes the df and df2 part to take a while.

Therefore, I'm searching for a way to only list the files that have been created today, because those are the ones I want to unzip to a location. So, essentially combining what's happening in `df` and `df2`.

```
date <- as.Date(Sys.Date(), origin = "01/01/1970", format= '%d/%m/%Y')
df <- file.info(list.files(sourcefolder, full.names = T)) 
df2 = df %>% 
  rownames_to_column() %>% 
  filter(as.Date(df$ctime, format = '%d/%m/%Y')==date)
```

Comment: Try using `df2 <- rownames(df)[as.Date(df$ctime) == Sys.Date()]`. Does it help ?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, and it did work in part (it converted the dataframe to a value) but it's not quite what I'm looking for. I'm looking for a way that applies a filter in the df part, so I don't need the df2 part.

Comment: You can just combine the two right? `file.info(list.files(sourcefolder, full.names = TRUE)) %>%
  rownames_to_column() %>%
  filter(as.Date(ctime) == Sys.Date())` ?

Comment: Yes, this seems to make it somewhat faster, Many thanks! Also, I'm beginning to believe the solution I had in mind isn't possible because that would involve a circular argument so this will do!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could combine the two steps and use

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)

list.files(sourcefolder, full.names = TRUE) %>% 
     file.info() %>%
     rownames_to_column() %>% 
     filter(as.Date(ctime) == Sys.Date())
```

If you have too many files in your `sourcefolder` try to narrow them down using `pattern` argument in `list.files` so you have only the files which you need and it will help to make this process faster.